# Node.JS Thrift server example gives "Cannot read property 'tls' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, thrift

I am trying to follow Thrift's [Node.JS tutorial](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/nodejs) but got `Cannot read property 'tls' of undefined`

Here are some background info:

OS: Windows 7

Node.JS version: v0.10.34

Thrift compiler version: 0.9.2

Here are my steps:

1. Get a thrift v0.9.2 Windows [here](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/thrift/0.9.2/thrift-0.9.2.exe)
2. Copy tutorial.thrift and shared.thrift (from tutorial) into an empty director `ProjRoot`
3. Generate .js files with the exe obtained from step1 `thrift.0.9.2 -r --gen js:node tutorial.thrift` and `shared.thrift`
4. create `package.json` with following content:

   ```
   {
     "name": "thrifttest",
     "version": "0.0.0",
     "private": true,
     "scripts": {
       "start": "node ./bin/www"
     },
     "dependencies": {
       "thrift": "~0.9.2"
     }
   }
   ```
5. put the server side code under the ***Server*** section into NodeServer.js
6. In terminal, run `npm install` then `node NodeServer.js`

And I got the following error:

```
...\ProjRoot\node_modules\thrift\lib\thrift\server.js:89
  if (options.tls) {
             ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tls' of undefined
    at Object.exports.createMultiplexServer (...\ProjRoot\node_modules\thrift\lib\thrift\s
erver.js:89:14)
    at Object.exports.createServer (...\ProjRoot\node_modules\thrift\lib\thrift\server.js:106:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (...\ProjRoot\NodeServer.js:8:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

Is it a bug? or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Link for the two thrift files: [tutorial.thrift](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob_plain;f=tutorial/tutorial.thrift), [shared.thrift](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob_plain;f=tutorial/shared.thrift)

Comment: Discussing this on the Thrift User mailing list could be a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Original answer**

I temporary work around this issue by changing the code at server.js from:

```
if (options.tls) {
    return tls.createServer(options.tls, serverImpl);
  } else {
    return net.createServer(serverImpl);
  }
```

to

```
return net.createServer(serverImpl);
```

That is removing the `if` statement.

I definitely look forward to a solution that truly addresses the problem

**Updated answer**
When creating the server,

```
var server = thrift.createServer(Calculator, {...})
```

The `createServer` signature expect a third argument `options`, passing an empty object to createServer

```
var server = thrift.createServer(Calculator, {...}, {})
                                                    ^
```

solves the problem